# When returning a number inside the getRandomNum it returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a game that allows the user to give 2 numbers and I need to give a random number between those 2 numbers and compare it to the numbers that they are guessing. I'm having problems comparing variables inside the function, which is the const variable `randomNum`, and a variable inside the `guessNumOne` function to see if they are equal or not. I tried to display the number just to make sure it actually assigns a number, but it doesn't: it says "undefined".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Guessing Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script>
    // assigns random variable
    function getRandomNum(start, end) {
      return Math.floor((Math.random() * (end - start)) + start);
    }

    // Assign global variables for userinput and the random number
    var start = parseInt(document.getElementById("numStart").value);
    var end = parseInt(document.getElementById("numEnd").value);
    var randomNum;
    randomNum = getRandomNum(start, end);

    // The function which checks if the random number equals the user inputs number
    function guessNumOne () {
      let firstGuess = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstGuess").value);
      let firstInputBox = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstGuess").value);
      let output = document.getElementById("answer");
      let correct = "You got it!";
      let incorrect = "Incorrect!";
      let randNum = randomNum;
      let disableInputOne = document.getElementById("firstGuess").disabled = false;
      let test = document.getElementById("display");
      test.innerText = randNum;
      if ( firstGuess != randNum) {
        firstInputBox.style.background = "red";
        output.innerHTML = wrong;
        disableInputOne = true;
      }
      if (firstGuess == randNum) {
        firstInputBox.style.background = "green";
        output.innerHTML = correct;
        disableInputOne = true;
        disableInputTwo = true;
        disableInputThree = true;
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 style="text-align: center"> Welcome to the Guessing Game!</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="numStart">Starting Number</label>
      <input type="number" name="numStart" id="numStart" class="form-control" placeholder="Starting Number">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="numEnd">Ending Number</label>
      <input type="number" name="numEnd" id="numEnd" class="form-control" placeholder="Ending Number">
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
    <div id = "display"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstGuess">Guess #1:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="firstGuess">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="firstSub" class="btn btn-primary">Guess</button>
    <div class="container" id="answer"></div>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("firstSub").addEventListener("click", guessNumOne);
      document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", guessNumOne);
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getRandomNum` takes two parameters but you never supply them when calling the function.

Comment: I think you forgot to pass the parameters while calling the function: `randomNum = getRandomNum(start, end);`

Comment: very dumb mistake, but it still says undefined :(

Comment: Can you paste a snippet? It would be easier to debug

Comment: In `firstInputBox` initialization `.value` is missing

Comment: I just added it! Thank you! but it is still giving me an undefined value

Answer (score 0):

```
var start = parseInt(document.getElementById("numStart").value);
var end = parseInt(document.getElementById("numEnd").value);
```

these code will not be executed and `start` and `end` is no value. they should be inside a function.

```
var start, end, randomNum;
            function getRandomNum(start, end) {
                return Math.floor((Math.random() * (end - start)) + start);
            }

            // Assign global variables for userinput and the random number

            

            // The function which checks if the random number equals the user inputs number
            function guessNumOne () {
                start = parseInt(document.getElementById("numStart").value);
                end = parseInt(document.getElementById("numEnd").value);
                randomNum = getRandomNum(start, end);
```